# unable to assign result of google-play-scraper to a variable

Tags: node.js, google-play

from the npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-scraper
I tried to assign the result of scrape to a variable.
But was unable to.

```
var gplay = require("google-play-scraper");
var app = gplay.app({ appId: "com.google.android.youtube" });
console.log(app);
```

the above code will print out

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

any ideas on how to assign it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = gplay.app({ appId: "com.google.android.youtube" });
app.then((result)=>console.log(result.title))
```

You have to use then to print the result (resolved)

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes two arguments: callback
>   functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

Comment: how do you extract things from the app?
for example, i just need the comments and title

Comment: Try my code if you get any result ,your promise is pending to  be resolved.